# Check if date is between 2 dates in xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0

XML example:

```
<Time>
...
<FromTime>12:00</FromTime>
<ToTime>14:00</ToTime>
...
</Time>
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:variable name="Hour" select="13:00"/>
<xsl:if test="FromTime &lt;= $Hour and ToTime &gt;= $Hour">
I am in
</xsl:if>
```

Can you point me in the right direction. My if not working as it should. I never get 'I am in'

Looks like the porblem is with `&lt;=`. If I just use `=` and change `Hour` to 12:00 it is working but not when I am using `&lt;=`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Convert timevalues to numbers with `number(translate(timevvalue,':',''))`

Comment: thank you. I didn't know that I need to convert it to numbers

Comment: but if is FromTime 12:30 then if is not working. Only if is 12:00 is working. What is wrong in statement?

Comment: did you convert both sides of comparison?